# How would I go about formatting a query based on value of Child Object

Tags: firebase

Tried to find an example with how to do something like this online. I am using the Firebase Web SDK

My goal is to query this tree, and return all of the subtrees that are equal to true. I wrote this up quickly as an example but the subtree's would represent objects, with Value being properties of objects field

```
Tree
---SubTree1
------Value: false
---SubTree2
------Value: true
---SubTree3
------Value: false
---SubTree4
------Value: true
---SubTree5
------Value: false
```

I know I could just return every object in the tree and then sort it out, but I feel like that is less efficient and I would be better off just getting objects which value is True

Anyway to do this? I tried to ask this question in a way that future searchers could benefit as well. THanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
firebase.database().ref('/Tree').orderByChild('Value').equalTo(true)
  .once('value')
  .then(snapshot => {
    const records = snapshot.val();
    console.log('Subtrees whose values are true: ', records);
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```